# Bound the norm of an integral on a not closed curve

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that $\left | \int_\gamma \frac{dz}{3+z^2} \right | < \frac{\pi}{3} $ where $\gamma$ is the upper unitary semicircle $ |z| = 1$.
What can I do when the curve is not closed?

Comment: Note that $\big|\frac{1}{3+z^2}\big|\leq \frac{1}{3-|z^2|}=\frac{1}{3-1}$ for all $z\in \gamma$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An explicit parametrization is perfectly doable:

$$ \int_\gamma\frac{dz}{3+z^2} = \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{i e^{i\theta}}{3+e^{2i\theta}}\,d\theta=i\int_{0}^{\pi}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^{n+1}}e^{(2n+1)i\theta}\,d\theta $$
equals
$$-\frac{2}{3}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{3^n(2n+1)}=-\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}$$
via the Maclaurin series of $\arctan(x)$. This also equals $-\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dz}{3+z^2}$ since $\frac{1}{3+z^2}$ is holomorphic over the region $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\text{Im}(z)\geq 0, |z|\leq 1\}$. In other terms, if the integration curve is not closed we may try to close it and consider the contributions provided by the poles inside it (zero, in this case) and the integral along the auxiliary curve/segment.